# Config mailer in Symfony 1.4 - how in admin panel, not factories.yml?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How can i do configuration of emails in admin panel in Symfony?
Default i must set this in file factories.yml:

```
mailer:
  class: sfMailer
  param:
    logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
    charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
    delivery_strategy: realtime
    transport:
      class: Swift_SmtpTransport
      param:
        host:       localhost
        port:       25
        encryption: ~
        username:   ~
        password:   ~
```

I would like set host, port, encryption, username and password in admin panel and keep this in my database. So how can i get this data from database if i send mail?

```
    $message = $this->getMailer()->compose(
      array('jobeet@example.com' => 'Jobeet Bot'),
      $affiliate->getEmail(),
      'Jobeet affiliate token',
      <<<EOF
Your Jobeet affiliate account has been activated.

Your token is {$affiliate->getToken()}.

The Jobeet Bot.
EOF
    );

    $this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

I can get this data from database :) but i dont know how to write in to getMailer().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an event fired [when the mailer is configured](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/tags/RELEASE_1_4_17/lib/mailer/sfMailer.class.php#L152).

```
$dispatcher->notify(new sfEvent($this, 'mailer.configure'));
```

So you can [add a listener](http://symfony.com/blog/using-the-symfony-event-system) on this event, retrieve the mailer object, and re-configure it.

Or, as describe in this snippet, you can built manually the call to the mailer and define how you set the config (and got the advantage to use getMailer in a task): http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/377